# Ehache RMI replication with Listener to remote Cache

Tags: spring-boot, ehcache-2

I am trying to create a event Listener to a remote cache . If any object added or updated to remote cache I want to perform an operation . Is this possible to do?

Here Remote Cache is the Producer and My Local Instance is the Consumer.

I am trying to do this in Spring Boot. I implemented a cacheEventListener but the notify methods are not being called in the receiver when producer updates the cache